# Why Does this Short?

Tags: power-supply, switches, dc-motor, short-circuit

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fgSint.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I'm new to electronics and wired a dc motor to a battery and switch. After the battery got really hot, I realized that it was probably a short circuit, but I don't understand why.

the positive wire from the battery and to the motor where connected to one side of the switch, while the negative of both where connected to the other side of the switch.

The motor turned very slowly when the switch was off and quickly when it was on.

Can someone help me understand what's going on or point me to good resources?

Thanks!

Comment: Not to sound rude but it's actually obvious why this short circuits. When you close that switch, your positive and negative terminals meet. Could you explain why you need a switch right there instead of just having a switch connect your positive terminal to one of the inputs to your motor?

Comment: I realize (now) that I should have hooked up the switch in series not parallel to turn the motor on and off. But I don't understand why the motor turned slowly in one state and fast in the other. Also, it seemed to heat up when off.

Comment: Well there you go haha :) Yes, your switch should be in series with your positive terminal of the battery to one of the terminals of the motor.

Comment: When "off" it's a short circuit. When you turn it "off", you're connecting one side of the battery, with the other side of the battery - isn't that what a short circuit *is*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is not how you connect a motor to a switch. You connect everything in series like so:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f5nQWx.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Such that opening the switch stops current from being able to flow into through the motor.

In your circuit, when the switch is closed the switch is much much lower resistance than the motor so most of the current goes through the switch instead of the motor. If the switch were zero resistance, all of the current would go through the switch and none would go through the motor. The current tries to take the easiest path through the circuit. The easier the path is relative to the alternate paths, the higher the proportion of the current will take that easy path. Therefore, the motor gets less power.

It short circuits because the battery tries to drive enough current through the switch and motor parallel combination so the voltage across it equals the battery's own voltage. That is how equilibrium is reached. With the small resistance of the switch, this takes a lot of current. More current than the battery can safely provide but it still tries to do it anyways (and heats up in the process). The battery tries so hard that it starts to buckle and the voltage sags.

You can now look at why the motor is running with less power from two different perspectives:

(a) The battery voltage sagging means less voltage across the motor so less current can be pushed through the motor.

(b) Most of the current produced is diverted through the switch around than the battery.

So it's really the same effect looked at from two different perspectives since you need sufficient voltage to push a certain current through the motor (or any load). They're not independent and you cannot have one without the other.

When the switch is open, all the current flows through the motor so it operates normally.

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense. I was also wondering why the motor seemed to go on (fast) when the switch was in the position that I thought was off.

Comment: I think you got mixed up in "if the switch had zero resistance  ..."

Comment: @Transistor Yeah, I caught that and just corrected it.

Comment: @BenyominWalters Open/closed or conducting/not conducting are the terms you use for switches since on/off are ambiguous. What is a switch doing when it's on? What is a switch doing when it's off? You can't assume that. Imagine a valve. It it a valve's job to let water pass? Or to block water? What ever it's job is would be the "on" state, except you can't assume what its job is.

Answer (score 1):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f2inMC.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Note this is assuming ideal parts.

**Reality check:** every part has resistance.

Battery (ESR) , wire {mOhms/meter}  Motor DCR coil resistance and switch.

**Each have current limits**

Current in loop I = V/R on startup then reduces and depends on mechanical load and RPM.

Comment: Thanks. How did you get the DC motor in the schematic I couldn't find it.

Comment: I faked it with an inductor

Answer (score 0):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fD1PVX.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

In other words, the switch bypasses the motor, thus causing a short since there is 0 resistance between the + and - terminals on the battery, but there will always be greater than 0 resistance on the motor.

Remember, **electricity flows through the path of least resistance.**

Good question, Benyomin!